# ¿como puedo meter los nombres de los ficheros en un arreglo en la funcion recursiva?

Tags: java, android, recursión

Con esta función puedo recolectar los nombres de los ficheros, ¿como puedo meterlos a un arreglo?

Codigo para leer archivos:

(on create)

```
 final File carpeta = new 
File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/cc.openframeworks.androidMultiOFActivitiesExample/files/pics");

 listarFicherosPorCarpeta(carpeta);



public void listarFicherosPorCarpeta(final File carpeta) {
    for (final File ficheroEntrada : carpeta.listFiles()) {
        if (ficheroEntrada.isDirectory()) {
            listarFicherosPorCarpeta(ficheroEntrada);
        } else {
            System.out.println(ficheroEntrada.getName());

        }

    }

}
```

Esto es lo que estoy intentando pero me marca error:

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public void listarFicherosPorCarpeta(final File carpeta) {
    for (final File ficheroEntrada : carpeta.listFiles()) {

        if (ficheroEntrada.isDirectory()) {
            listarFicherosPorCarpeta(ficheroEntrada);
        } else {
            System.out.println(ficheroEntrada.getName());

           for(int i=0; i< ficheroEntrada.length(); i++)
               list.add(ficheroEntrada[i].getName());

        }
    }
}
```

Esta parte me marca error:

```
   list.add(ficheroEntrada[i].getName());
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El problema es particularmente que no sabes como hacer un arreglo, que no sabes como usar un arreglo en una funcion recursiva o cual es exactamente el problema_

Comment: Disculpa @gbianchi no se como usarlo en la función recursiva.

Comment: claro, lo que deseas realizar es muy sencillo, enseguida te agrego una respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @Jorgesys donde puedo ver la respuesta?

Comment: En la sección de respuestas sobre la pregunta, revisa [answer], ahí los usuarios de la comunidad agregan las respuestas sobre la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, si ya lei las reglas pero no encuentro la respuesta.

Comment: Nadie respondio tu pregunta todavia. Tranquilo, alguien podra explicarte tu problema.

Comment: Lee por favor el [tour] asi sabes como funciona el sitio

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi, ya lei las ligas que mandaron y el recorrido. Ya tengo claro como funciona el sitio, solo que Jorgesys dijo que iba agregar una respuesta.

Comment: Y puede que este ocupado. Si dijo que iba a agregar una respuesta, en cuanto pueda lo hara. El u otra persona. Tene en cuenta que todas las personas que aportan a este sitio lo hacen voluntariamente y a su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Tu podiras ayudarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu método recursivo para leer los archivos en un directorio es correcto, solo necesitas almacenar los nombres en el `ArrayList`,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public void listarFicherosPorCarpeta(final File carpeta) {
    for (final File ficheroEntrada : carpeta.listFiles()) {
        if (ficheroEntrada.isDirectory()) {
            listarFicherosPorCarpeta(ficheroEntrada);
        } else {
            System.out.println(ficheroEntrada.getName());

            //Almacena nombres de archivos a lista.
            list.add(ficheroEntrada.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

Ahora para obtener el array simplemente convierte el list en el cual se almacenaron los nombres de archivo a un array:

```
final File carpeta = new 
File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/cc.openframeworks.androidMultiOFActivitiesExample/files/pics");
 listarFicherosPorCarpeta(carpeta);

 //Convierte la lista en un array de Strings.
 String[] ficheros = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

 //Imprime nombres almacenados.
 System.out.println("archivos almacenados: " + Arrays.toString(ficheros));
```